# My SharePoint Online Management shell is not showing anymore inside my "All Programs", when i created a new user profile inside my PC

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, installation, pnp-powershell

I have windows 7 64-bit. and i install SharePoint management shell long time ago, and it used to appear under my "All Programs" menu. now last week my user profile got corrupted, so our system admin team created a new user profile for me. after doing so the sharepoint management shell disappeared from my "All Programs" menu. now i can find the related .dll files as follow:-

[image]

but not sure how i can open the SP online management shell and run some pnp scripts?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to when you install something in Windows, it gives the option sometimes to "Install for All Users" or "Install for Current User Only".

This doesn't mean it's not "installed" on the PC, since it's available from the Program Files, you may just have to pin it yourself to the Start Menu, or try "re-installing" under the new user. If you try the Control Panels program manager, try "Repairing" the install for that software to see if that adds it or gives the option to pin to start menu.

If not, just find the .exe file and pin it to your start menu yourself. Ultimately the Start Menu is just a bunch of folders, you can build it out and name it however you like.

UPDATE:

If you can't find the shortcut (it may be created under the user profile explicitly on install), you should be able to create your own shortcut with something like this in the target:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
```

... that just starts powershell and automatically adds the SharePoint snapin, which is no different from what you originally had.

Another options is to just run powershell normally, then add the SharePoint snapin manually as needed using:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```